# Oracle Counting Values in Groups that have not Already Been Counted

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I have not had any luck solving this problem and could use some insight.

I have a series of data like this:

```
Date|Item
1   |A
1   |B
2   |C
3   |A
```

I am trying to group them together so my result will show me the number of previously uncounted items, like this:

```
Date|Item
1   |2
2   |1
3   |0
```

I have been using `COUNT DISTINCT`, but that would give me a `1` under Date 3, which is double counting. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this problem? I'm not sure what else to try on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` with `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    t1. Date, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.Date IS NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2
    ON t2.Date < t1.Date
    AND t2.Item = t1.Item
GROUP BY t1.Date
```

Comment: I'll give that a try and let you know if I have problems, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Group the rows by item, and for each item select `min(dt)`. (Note: don't use reserved keywords like `date` as column names!)

Then group the resulting rows again, by `min(dt)` (aliased as `dt`) and count the rows.

No need for expensive joins, correlated subqueries, etc.

```
with
     test_data ( dt, item ) as (
       select 1, 'A' from dual union all
       select 1, 'B' from dual union all
       select 2, 'C' from dual union all
       select 3, 'A' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select dt, count(*) as ct
from   ( select   min(dt) as dt, item
         from     test_data
         group by item
       )
group by dt
;

        DT         CT
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          1
```

However, this will miss dt = 3 in the output. If you want to keep it, you will need to use an analytic analog of this solution. Still no joins! Something like:

```
with
     test_data ( dt, item ) as (
       select 1, 'A' from dual union all
       select 1, 'B' from dual union all
       select 2, 'C' from dual union all
       select 3, 'A' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select dt, count(case when ord = 1 then 'x' end) as ct
from   (
         select dt, item, count(*) over (partition by item order by dt) ord
         from   test_data
       )
group by dt
;

        DT         CT
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          1
         3          0
```